# Have Enemies Shoot at Player Problem? pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make my enemy shoot my player but for some reason the bullets arent showing nor they are shooting at the player I don't even know why, I even draw the bullets on my window  [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/d8789b2ae6d7e0ec3aa71fe215d97ebc)

```
bulls = []
runninggame = True
while runninggame:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runninggame = False

    for bull in bulls:
        if bull.x < 500 and bull.x > 0:
            bull.x += bull.vel  # Moves the bullet by its vel
        else:
            for enemys in enemying:
                if playerman.x - 100 <= enemys.x <= playerman.x + 100 and playerman.y - 100 <= enemys.y <= playerman.y + 100:
                    bulls.pop(bulls.index(bull))
                    bulls.append(enemybullets(round(enemys.x+enemys.width//2), round(enemys.y + enemys.height//2), 6, (0,0,0), facing))
```

then I called it below

```
    for bull in bulls:
        bull.draw(window)
```

my enemy projectile class

```
# enemys bullets
class enemybullets(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,radius,color,facing):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.facing = facing
        self.vel = 8 * facing

    def draw(self,win):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x,self.y), self.radius)
```

Comment: first in every loop calculate distance between enemy and player to see how far it is. You can use [pygame.math](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html) for this. And use `if/else` to check if emeny/player stand left of right. And if it close enought then create object `Bullet()` and add to list which you have to check in every loop - move bullets, check colision with player, and draw it.

Comment: BTW: to make code more readable use CamelCaseNames for classes - ie. `class Player`, `class Enemy`, and `lower_case_names` for variables, functions and methods - ie, `self.walking_index`. And put all classes before `pygame.init()`.  See more [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: if you put code on pastebin then put link to normal page - not `raw` - and set `language: python` to make code highlighted - it will be more readable.

Comment: I changed the link can you further explain because I dont really understand I fairly new to pygame

Comment: you have class Player and Enemy - create similar class Bullet. You have list to keep enemies - create similar list for bullets. In main loop in every loop you check enemy collision with player - in every loop check also distance to player. You can use [pygame.math.Vector2.distance_to](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.distance_to). When distance and direction is OK then create Bullet (with correct direction and speed) and add list for bullets. In every loop you move Enemy - similar way you move bullets.

Comment: I have updated what I did I have a quit a problem

Comment: BTW: using `math.sqrt(enemys.x**2 + enemys.y**2)` you calculate distance from enemy to point `(0,0)`. To calculate distance from enemy to player you have to use something like this `sqrt( (player.x - enemys.x)**2 + (player.y - enemys.y)**2)`.

Comment: idk still kills the enemy instead of shooting at the player

Comment: use `print()` to display values in variables in different monents and display info which part of code is executed - it is called `"print debuging"`. OR learn how to use real debuger.

Comment: Full code???????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code of a very similar game I made with the help of a tutorial some time ago.

My first suggestion is try reducing the velocity of the bullets.That way you can make sure that you are not missing anything that's on the screen.

Next make sure that you are updating the screens contents properly.

It is difficult to give a comprehensive answer without having a look at your full code.I have included my code here so that you could reference and fix the issue.

Hope this helps.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 480))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

char = pygame.image.load('standing.png')

bulletSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('gshot.wav')
shotHit = pygame.mixer.Sound('bounce.wav')
backSound = pygame.mixer.music.load('music.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)


walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.png'), pygame.image.load('L2.png'), pygame.image.load('L3.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L4.png'), pygame.image.load('L5.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L6.png'), pygame.image.load('L7.png'), pygame.image.load('L8.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L9.png')]

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R6.png'), pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R9.png')]

b_walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1E.png'), pygame.image.load('L2E.png'), pygame.image.load('L3E.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L4E.png'), pygame.image.load('L5E.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L6E.png'), pygame.image.load('L7E.png'), pygame.image.load('L8E.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L9E.png'), pygame.image.load('L10E.png'), pygame.image.load('L11E.png')]
b_walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1E.png'), pygame.image.load('R2E.png'), pygame.image.load('R3E.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R4E.png'), pygame.image.load('R5E.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R6E.png'), pygame.image.load('R7E.png'), pygame.image.load('R8E.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R9E.png'), pygame.image.load('R10E.png'), pygame.image.load('R11E.png')]

pygame.display.set_caption("My Samurai(v1.0)")

x, y = 50, 50
bx, by = 250, 250
p_width, p_height = 40, 50
b_width, b_height = 40, 50

jumpCount = 5
walkCount = 0


class bullets:

    def __init__(self, x, y, surface, mov_speed):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.surface = surface
        self.mov_speed = mov_speed

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(self.surface, (200, 20, 20), (self.x, self.y), 3, 1)
        self.x += self.mov_speed






class figure:

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, surface):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.surface = surface
        self.jumpCount = 5
        self.jump = False
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.move = False
        self.maxCount = 0
        self.hitboxWidth = 55
        self.hitboxHeight = 55
        self.hitbox = [self.x, self.y, self.hitboxWidth, self.hitboxHeight]

    def p_jump(self):
        if self.jump:
            print("i came here")
            if self.jumpCount > 0:
                self.y -= int((self.jumpCount ** 2) / 2) * 6
                self.jumpCount -= 1
                print("im here 1", self.jumpCount, "y pos", self.y)
            else:
                self.y += int((self.jumpCount ** 2) / 2) * 6
                self.jumpCount -= 1
                print("i came here 2", self.jumpCount)

            if self.jumpCount == -6:
                self.jumpCount = 5
                self.jump = False
                print(jump)

    def draw(self, dirL, dirR, surface, arrayL, arrayR):
        #pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, (255, 0, 0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1], self.hitboxWidth, self.hitboxHeight), 1)
        if dirL:
            if self.move:
                surface.blit(arrayL[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
            else:
                surface.blit(arrayL[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))

        if dirR:
            if self.move:
                surface.blit(arrayR[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
            else:
                surface.blit(arrayR[self.walkCount // 3], (self.x, self.y))

        if self.walkCount > self.maxCount:
            self.walkCount = 0


speed = 5
jump = False
run = True
left = False
right = True
player = figure(x, y, p_width, p_height, win)
beast = figure(bx, by, b_width, b_height, win)
player.maxCount = 24
beast.maxCount = 30
beast.move = True
player.hitboxWidth = 42
beast.hitboxWidth = 42
body = []
i = 0
bSpeed = 8
score = 0
score_font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 20, 1, 1)
hit_font = pygame.font.SysFont('calibri', 80, 1, 1)
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(50)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(27)
    bg = pygame.image.load('bg.jpg')
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    score_display = score_font.render("Score: {}".format(score), 1, (0, 0, 0))
    win.blit(score_display, (700, 10))
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and player.x > 0:
        player.x -= speed
        left = True
        right = False
        player.move = True
        bSpeed = -8
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and player.x + p_width + speed + 5 < 800:
        player.x += speed
        left = False
        right = True
        player.move = True
        bSpeed = 8
    else:
        player.move = False
        player.walkCount = 0

    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and player.y > 0 and not jump:
        player.y -= speed
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and player.y + p_height + speed + 5 < 480 and not jump:
        player.y += speed
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        player.jump = True
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and i <= 0:
        body.append(bullets(player.x + 32, player.y + 40, win, bSpeed))
        i = 4
        bulletSound.play()
    for bullet in body:
        bullet.draw()
        if beast.x + 25 < bullet.x < beast.x + beast.hitboxWidth:
            if beast.y < bullet.y < beast.y + beast.hitboxHeight:
                body.pop(body.index(bullet))
                score += 1
                shotHit.play()


    # beast position cal
    if beast.x - player.x > 0:
        b_right = False
        b_left = True
        beast.x -= int((beast.x - player.x) * 0.025)
    else:
        b_right = True
        b_left = False
        beast.x -= int((beast.x - player.x) * 0.025)

    if beast.y - player.y > 0:
        beast.y -= int((beast.y - player.y) * 0.025)
    else:
        beast.y -= int((beast.y - player.y) * 0.025)

    if i > 0:
        i -= 1

    player.p_jump()
    player.draw(left, right, win, walkLeft, walkRight)
    beast.draw(b_left, b_right, win, b_walkLeft, b_walkRight)

    player.hitbox = [player.x + 10, player.y + 8, player.hitboxWidth, player.hitboxHeight]
    beast.hitbox = [beast.x + 10, beast.y + 5, beast.hitboxWidth, beast.hitboxHeight]

    if (player.hitbox[0] < beast.hitbox[0] < player.hitbox[0] + player.hitbox[2] - 20) or\
            (player.hitbox[0] + 15 < beast.hitbox[0] + beast.hitbox[2] <= player.hitbox[0] + player.hitbox[2]):
        if (player.hitbox[1] < beast.hitbox[1] < player.hitbox[1] + player.hitbox[3] - 10) or\
                (player.hitbox[1] + 10 < beast.hitbox[1] + beast.hitbox[3] < player.hitbox[1] + player.hitbox[3]):
            score -= 5
            hit_display = hit_font.render("-5", 1, (255, 0, 0))
            win.blit(hit_display, (400, 200))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
            player.x, player.y = 100, 100
            beast.x, beast.y = 600, 300
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False



pygame.quit()
```

Comment: heres my code https://pastebin.com/TpMRaM7Y so I see in your code and I am kinda confused because  witch part does make the bullet follow the enemy here I have made a new thread explaining things https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62274195/how-can-i-make-my-enemys-projectile-attack-the-player-where-ever-the-player-move?noredirect=1#comment110146794_62274195

Comment: So it appears  that you managed to fix your issue with the bullets not appearing on the screen.Would be helpful for someone in the future if you could briefly tell what went wrong.

Comment: k also please dont forget to explain how you made the enemys bullets follow the player! on my new thread