# How Can I Make My Enemys Projectile Attack The Player Where Ever The Player Moves?

Tags: python, pygame

I have an enemy that shoots projectiles but only shoots to the right I want it to shoot at the player with any position I don't know how to do that heres a [vid](https://gyazo.com/046af29a4ef0331f1e522571dcf30e8e) what I have done so fare if you could walk me throw the steps on how to do it that would be great Thank You

this is what I have done so fare it only shoots to the right I want it to shoot at the player within any position the player is at

```
   for shootss in shootsright:
       if shootss.x < 500 and shootss.x > 0:
           shootss.x += 7
       else:
           shootsright.pop(shootsright.index(shootss))
   if len(shootsright) < 1:
           shootsright.append(Bools(round(enemyshoots1.x+enemyshoots1.width-107),round(enemyshoots1.y + enemyshoots1.height-50),(0,0,0)))
```

and here is my bullet class

```
# enemys bullets
ksud = pygame.image.load("heart.png")
class Bools(object):
  def __init__(self, x, y,color):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
      self.ksud = pygame.image.load("heart.png")
      self.hitbox  = self.ksud.get_rect()
      self.rect  = self.ksud.get_rect()
      self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
      self.speed = 10
      self.color = color
      self.hitbox = (self.x + 57, self.y + 33, 29, 52) # NEW
  def draw(self, window):
       self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
       player_rect = self.ksud.get_rect(center = self.rect.center) 
       player_rect.centerx += 0 # 10 is just an example
       player_rect.centery += 0 # 15 is just an example
       window.blit(self.ksud, player_rect)
       self.hitbox = (self.x + 97, self.y + 33, 10, 10) # NEW
       window.blit(self.ksud,self.rect)
```

my enemys class

```
shotsright = pygame.image.load("shooting2.png")
shotsleft = pygame.image.load("shooting1.png")
class enemyshoot:
   def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
       self.x = x
       self.y =y
       self.height = height
       self.width = width
       self.color = color
       self.shootsright = pygame.image.load("shooting2.png")
       self.shotsleft = pygame.image.load("shooting1.png")
       self.shootsright = pygame.transform.scale(self.shootsright,(self.shootsright.get_width()//3,self.shootsright.get_height()//3))
       self.shotsleft = pygame.transform.scale(self.shotsleft,(self.shotsleft.get_width()//3,self.shotsleft.get_height()//3))

       self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
       self.health = 10
       self.hitbox = (self.x + -20, self.y + 30, 31, 57)
   def draw(self):
       self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
       window.blit(self.shootsright,self.rect)
       self.hits = (self.x + 20, self.y, 28,60)
       pygame.draw.rect(window, (255,0,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 60, 50, 10)) # NEW
       pygame.draw.rect(window, (0,255,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 60, 50 - (5 * (10 - self.health)), 10))
       self.hitbox = (self.x + 60, self.y + 80, 81, 87)

black = (0,0,0)
enemyshoots1 = enemyshoot(1100,240,100,100,black)        
enemyshooting = [enemyshoots1]
```

here is my full code
[script](https://pastebin.com/TpMRaM7Y)

Comment: you have a lot of lines of code, you should try to clean it up a bit, for example, you could have every sprite/ object in one list so when you want to scroll, you only need to loop through one list instead of all of those loops, same for drawing. also you could try to create one master class and then build the other classes on top of that class, you also have a lot of blank lines, you could probably cut the lines down a lot

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your script didn't help me a lot as you are maintaining many different classes.

```
   for shootss in shootsright:
       if shootss.x < 500 and shootss.x > 0:
           shootss.x += 7
```

Here it appears that when you are updating your bullets x coordinate you are incrementing it with a positive constant value.

And then you update it like this in your bullet class.

```
   window.blit(self.ksud,self.rect)
```

What you can do instead is have a bullet speed that changes its direction.You can use a code like this

```
if object_you_want_to_follow.x > object_shooting_the_bullet.x:
    bulletSpeed = +7
elif object_you_want_to_follow.x < object_shooting_the_bullet.x:
    bulletSpeed = -7
```

Same applies if you want to follow it vertically along the y direction.

**OPTIMIZATION TIP**

From what i understand having this in your bullet class makes no difference as you are updating it soon after.

```
   window.blit(self.ksud, player_rect)
```

**EDIT**

To make things easier you can simply do this

```
   for shootss in shootsright:
       if shootss.x < 500 and shootss.x > 0:
           if enemy.x < playerman.x:
               shootss.x += 7
           else:
               shootss.x -= 7
       else:
           shootsright.pop(shootsright.index(shootss))
   if len(shootsright) < 1:
           shootsright.append(Bools(round(enemyshoots1.x+enemyshoots1.width-107),round(enemyshoots1.y + enemyshoots1.height-50),(0,0,0)))
```

Comment: am I doing something  wrong [image](https://gyazo.com/53e68f69a90948f0ac3f6b95d472cc84) it seems like the bullet just dont move at all what do you mean by `object shooting the bullets` are you talking about the part where I said `for shootss in shootsright` I idk if I have an object that shoots the bullet I just made the bullet stand next the enemy shoot gun

Comment: `object_shooting_bullets` is the enemy in your game.Anyway what you have done seems correct with just one problem.It appears that there is an indentation problem in the code you have shown.Your `elif` and `else` statements should be indented.

Comment: it follows the player but its not [vid](https://gyazo.com/ae1893e2399e0522039452898e7c4bbb) like shooting where the player is at and its just hoovering over its head

Comment: Yes,I'm sorry.Look at the changes i made to the if condition.You should change ***shootss.x*** to ***enemy.x***.Thats because you should be deciding the direction of the bullets based on where the enemy is relative to the player.

Comment: its working but its still not attacking the player just above it, it looks like its moving just its x axis  [vid](https://gyazo.com/af2b3dbb8eb54f465e288e1c17b37b96)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215720/discussion-between-afijaabb-and-habib-ismail).